# nextLine in Java returning unexpected results

Tags: java, file, io

This code does not work as expected:

```
int x=in.nextInt();
String y=in.nextLine();
System.out.println(y);
```

but the program terminates after getting a value for x.

However, if I write this then it works:

```
String y=in.nextLine();
int x=in.nextInt();    
System.out.println(y);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Check the output of the program for an exception - it's almost certainly there.

Comment: Without knowing what your input is, it's impossible to confidently answer your question. Please show us your input.

Comment: Without seeing an error, most likely the next token being returned is not an `int`, and therefore throws an exception

Comment: Add this line - `in.nextLine();` immediately below this line - `int x=in.nextInt();` in the first snippet.

Comment: @Lion it works what is the concept that extra in.nextLine() using before string input

Comment: I'd imagine it depends on who's doing the "expecting".

Comment: @Rocky16 : It's because when you use `Scanner#nextInt()`, it does not consume the new line (or other delimiter) itself so the next token returned will typically be an empty string. Thus, you need to follow it with an extra `Scanner#nextLine()`. It's for this reason, personally I rarely use the `nextInt()` method. I generally use `nextLine()` and parse the input to a desired type.

Comment: @Lion can you post it as answer to  accept the answer

Comment: @Rocky16 : I could but the answer posted by Cairnarvon indicates the same thing and there is no meaning to duplicate that answer with my answer. Just mark this as an accepted answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that your input is something like "12<Return>abc".

What happens is that after the call to `nextInt()`, there's a newline left in the stdin buffer. Your call to `nextLine()` consumes it, and your String `y` contains `"\n"`. When you print that, it looks blank, confusing you into thinking `nextLine()` was never called. The input you thought you should be getting remains in the stdin buffer.

Clear out the newline by calling `nextLine()` twice and discarding the first result.